# Identical pages in two (somewhat) identical Eclipse JSF/Primefaces apps render differently

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

I'm having a primefaces rendering issue in one Eclipse App but not in another.  I've compared web.xml's and pom's and tried to make them identical, at least as far as dependencies which might affect the rendering of primefaces. I've cleaned the offending project, updated the project under Maven, checked project facets, etc, but I still can't get the one app to render primefaces components the way they look in another app or in the showcase.

I reduced a page down to its simplest case using two primefaces buttons and identical templates with no additional CSS files.  Here's how each app renders the buttons:

*bad rendering, show with pointer hovering over top button*
[image: bad rendering, show with pointer hovering over top button]

*good rendering, which proper hover highlight and rounded corners*
[image]

the button spacings are also different. In the bad rendering there also appears to be some extra border outlining the whole canvas (white content area)

Facelet:

```
<h:body>
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/hmmcommonLayout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">title</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
            <p:button outcome="hr" value="With Icon" icon="ui-icon-star">
                <f:param name="productId" value="24" />
            </p:button>
        </h:form>
        <h:form>
            <p:button outcome="hr" icon="ui-icon-star" title="Icon Only">
            </p:button>
        </h:form>
        <br></br>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">
<h:head>
<title><ui:insert name="title">template title</ui:insert></title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
<div class="logoText">template logo text</div>
<ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The generated html is basically identical.  What else can I check??

Comment: Did you check the themes ? Are they the same version ?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a conflict between richfaces and primefaces.  Both Eclipse projects POM's contained primefaces and richfaces dependencies. The project rendering things properly had the following in its web.xml. Once I added these statements to my second project's web.xml things rendered properly there as well.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>plain</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```